# Is it appropriate to use the nusach of Rosh Hashanah on the days until Yom Kippur?

Tags: minhag, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot, high-holidays

Is it appropriate or inappropriate to use the nusach of the High Holy Days when davening on the days in between Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur? Because we put additions into the Amidah (Zokhreinu, etc) that are used in the Rosh Hashanah liturgy, I have heard people say these additions and their accompanying brachot using the melody from Rosh Hashanah.

This does not *feel* wrong to me. If that melody helps to remind you that we are in the Days of Awe and are being judged, there could be a positive benefit to it. I have never read anywhere that this is a recommended or even permissible practice though, and so while I have occasionally caught myself doing it, it may not be a good idea. Are there any sources that speak to whether this is appropriate, or at a minimum harmless?

Comment: Are there any rules governing melodies?

Comment: Rb Matisyahu Salomon is fond of the idea of using the tune of the yamim noraim to yourself during tefillah, to remind yourself of the yamim noraim. A mekubal I once spoke to, on the other hand, was averse to this idea as he said it would be me'orrer the middas ha'din.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately I've forgotten the source, but I remember having heard that you shouldn't use high holiday melodies during a normal Shabbat for example. However, this is a borderline case.